# Filter out a series by taking the intersecting index with respect to other series

Tags: python, pandas, merge, series

I have 2 pandas `Series` (x and y) with some Time values in common

Then I need to filter out one of them by taking just the values whose date index are common.

Let s say a series x

```
2010-01-27 16:00:00    2.0
2010-01-27 16:10:00    2.2
2010-01-27 16:30:00    1.7
```

and another y

```
2010-01-27 15:50:00    5.0
2010-01-27 16:00:00    2.8
2010-01-27 16:10:00    3.2
2010-01-27 16:20:00    4.2
2010-01-27 16:30:00    1.9
```

I want to filter y by comparing the respective indexes of x and y series

The result for y should be something like

```
2010-01-27 16:00:00    2.8
2010-01-27 16:10:00    3.2
2010-01-27 16:30:00    1.9
```

I tried with a simple

```
y[y.index.get_values()==x.index.get_values()]
```

but does not produce a series output. Is there something similar to `merge` in `Dataframes` for `Series`?

I do not want to combine both `Series` in a dataframe just compare them and take the common data index values

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and `get_duplicates`:

```
s = pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=0).sort_index()
print s

2010-01-27 15:50:00    5.0
2010-01-27 16:00:00    2.0
2010-01-27 16:00:00    2.8
2010-01-27 16:10:00    2.2
2010-01-27 16:10:00    3.2
2010-01-27 16:20:00    4.2
2010-01-27 16:30:00    1.7
2010-01-27 16:30:00    1.9

print s2[s.index.get_duplicates()]

2010-01-27 16:00:00    2.8
2010-01-27 16:10:00    3.2
2010-01-27 16:30:00    1.9
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

Or use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.duplicated.html):

```
print s2[s.index[s.index.duplicated()]]

2010-01-27 16:00:00    2.8
2010-01-27 16:10:00    3.2
2010-01-27 16:30:00    1.9
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

---

But the best is [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) or [`reindex_like`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex_like.html):

```
print s2.reindex(s1.index)

2010-01-27 16:00:00    2.8
2010-01-27 16:10:00    3.2
2010-01-27 16:30:00    1.9
Name: 1, dtype: float64

print s2.reindex_like(s1)

2010-01-27 16:00:00    2.8
2010-01-27 16:10:00    3.2
2010-01-27 16:30:00    1.9
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```